# Finding EV and variance of the number of times a word occurs

Tags: probability

Consider an iid sequence $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_{n+1}$ taking values 0 or 1 with probability distribution
$$P\{X_i=1\} = 1-P\{X_i=0\} = p.$$
Uniformly choose $M$ fragments $F_1, F_2, \dots, F_M$ of length 2 starting in the interval $[1,n]$, that is, $F_i = \left(X_{j_i}, X_{j_i+1}\right)$ for some $1 \leq j_i \leq n$. Let $W=(1,1)$.

Let $N_W$ be the number of times the word $W$ occurs among the $M$ fragments. Calculate $\mathbb{E}(N_W)$.

Calculate the probability $P(F_1=W, F_2=W)$.

Calculate $\text{Var}(N_W)$.

In the problem, it says we can ignore boundary effect due to time constraints.

Clearly, $P\left( \left(X_i,X_{i+1}\right) = W\right) = P(X_i=1)P(X_{i+1}=1) = p^2$ for any $i$. For the first part, I think (but am not sure) I can say

$$\mathbb{E}(N_W) = \sum_{i=1}^M \mathbb{E}1_{\{F_i=W\}} = Mp^2.$$

As for the second part, we write $P(F_1=W, F_2=W) = P\left( \left(X_{j_1}, X_{j_1+1}\right) = (1,1), \left(X_{j_2}, X_{j_2+1}\right) = (1,1) \right)$, and so, there are three cases:

1. There is no overlap, i.e. $j_2 \neq j_1-1, j_1, j_1+1$ happens with probability $(n-3)/n$.
   $$P(F_1=W,F_2=W) = p^4$$
2. There is one overlap, i.e. $j_2 = j_1-1, j_1+1$ happens with probability $2/n$.
   $$P(F_1=W,F_2=W) = p^3$$
3. Complete overlap, i.e. $j_2=j_1$ happens with probability $1/n$.
   $$P(F_1=W, F_2=W) = p^2$$

Thus,
$$P(F_1=W, F_2=W) = \frac{n-3}{n}p^4 + \frac{2}{n}p^3 + \frac{1}{n}p^2.$$

Is this correct? And I don't even know how to approach the third part.

Any hint would be appreciated!

Comment: I think you have to combine all cases together to answer the question 1. But it seems for me the solution can be obtained easier. Also to calculate the second moment you have to use the same logic as for mean and after this $Var(N_w)=E(N_w^2)-E(N_W)^2$.  May be I will write a solution later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a straightforward computation. Let $Y_i = 1_{\{X_i=1\}}$
\begin{align*}
\text{Var}(N_W) &= \text{Var}\left( \sum_{i=1}^M Y_{j_i}Y_{j_i+1} \right) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^M \text{Var}(Y_{j_1}Y_{j_1+1}) + \sum_{i \neq k} \text{Cov}(Y_{j_i}Y_{j_i+1}, Y_{j_k}Y_{j_k+1}) \\
&= M\text{Var}(Y_{j_1}Y_{j_1+1}) + 2\sum_{i=1}^{M-1} \text{Cov}(Y_{j_i}Y_{j_i+1}, Y_{j_i+1}Y_{j_i+2}) \\
&= M\text{Var}(Y_{j_1}Y_{j_1+1}) + 2(M-1)\text{Cov}(Y_{j_1}Y_{j_1+1}, Y_{j_1+1}Y_{j_1+2}) \\
&= M\left(\mathbb{E}Y_{j_1}Y_{j_1+1} - \left(\mathbb{E}Y_{j_1}Y_{j_1+1}\right)^2 \right) \\ &\quad + 2(M-1) \left(\mathbb{E}Y_{j_1}Y_{j_1+1}Y_{j_1+2} - \left(\mathbb{E}Y_{j_1}Y_{j_1+1}\right)\left(\mathbb{E}Y_{j_1+1}Y_{j_1+2}\right)\right) \\
&= M(p^2 - p^4) + 2(M-1)(p^3-p^4)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

I got a different answer. May be I made mistake somewhere.
OK we randomly choose $M$ pair. The way how you choose the fragments is equivalent to $M$ independent drawing of two numbers from the set of $n$ (and putting them back). 
So always the probability the pair be equal $(1,1)$ is $p^2$ like you wrote. 
Now lets denote $N_w(M)$ as a function of  $M$ drawning:
Now we can easily built the following recurrent  relation:
$$ 
E(N_w(M))=p^2(E(N_w(M-1))+1)+(1-p^2)E(N_w(M-1))=E(N_w(M-1))+p^2=Mp^2\\
E(N_w(M)^2)=p^2((E[N_w(M-1)+1)^2]+(1-p^2)(E[N_w(M-1)^2]=E[N_w(M-1)^2]+2p^2E[N_w(M-1)]+p^2=E[N_w(M-1)^2]+2p^4(M-1)+p^2
$$
So 
$$
Var(N_w(M))=E(N_w(M)^2)-(E(N_w(M)))^2=Var(N_w(M-1))+2p^4(M-1)+p^2-p^4-2p^4(M-1)=
Var(N_w(M-1))+p^2-p^4=M(p^2-p^4)
$$